# about to which vs. as to which

Tags: prepositions

Is it correct to say "I'm confused as to which of the following sentences is correct"? or "I'm confused about to which..."?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

"I'm confused as to which of the following sentences is correct" is correct, if a bit formal.

You could also say, more informally, "I'm confused which of these sentences is correct."

Comment: Your second example is incorrect English.

Comment: It's perfectly fine in my idiolect.

Comment: It would be fine if there was a pause or full stop between the clauses or utterances "I'm confused. Which of these sentences is correct?"

Comment: and is correct to say "I'm confused with wich one..."?

Answer (score 1):

- "I'm confused as to which of the following sentences is correct"

is good English.

- "I'm confused about which of the following sentences is correct"

is also correct. The additional "to" is incorrect.